# Ipv6 Network unreachable Debian

Tags: debian, ipv6

Been trying to configure ipv6 on my proxmox server for about an hour now and I just can't seem to get it right.

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address xxx.xxx.xxx.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.1
    bridge_ports eth2
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0

iface vmbr0 inet6 static
    address 2604:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:0000:0000:0000:0002
    netmask 64
    gateway 2604:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:0000:0000:0000:0001
```

ip -6 route

```
2604:xxx:x:2::/64 dev vmbr0  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 0
fe80::1 dev venet0  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 0
fe80::/64 dev venet0  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 0
fe80::/64 dev eth2  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 0
fe80::/64 dev vmbr0  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 0
default via 2604:xxx:x:2::1 dev vmbr0  metric 1024  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 0
```

ping6 google.com

```
PING google.com(dfw06s46-in-x0e.1e100.net) 56 data bytes
From 2604:xxx:x:2::2 icmp_seq=2 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From 2604:xxx:x:2::2 icmp_seq=3 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
From 2604:xxx:x:2::2 icmp_seq=4 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
```

Would appreciate any help that could be provided. It is probably something pretty simple but I am a bit new to debian.

Comment: `/128` is not a valid prefix length on an ethernet, ethernet-like, or other multi-access device. That's only valid on loopback and point-to-point interfaces. The correct prefix length has to be something else, most likely `/64`.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of that. Now i have gotten a bit further and just get "Destination unreachable: Address unreachable" on pings

Comment: Please edit your question to show the new prefix length being used, and revise the output of `ip -6 route` because now it's probably different than it was before.

Comment: Updated as requested

Comment: Are you able to ping the gateway address? If not then how about pinging the gateway on its link local address?

Comment: Cannot ping the gateway address or the gateway on the link local.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21598/discussion-between-awmusic12635-and-celada).